# How to Use AgentBuilder replace the method of class

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I can redefine the class to replace `Foo`'s method to `Bar`'s  like this ：

```java
   ByteBuddy byteBuddy = new ByteBuddy();
        byteBuddy
                .redefine(Bar.class)
                .name(Foo.class.getName())
                .make()
                .load(Foo.class.getClassLoader(),
                        ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent());

Foo foo = new Foo()
foo.m()
// output is bar
```

How can I  use `AgentBuilder` do the same work , replace  all `Foo`'s methods  , not delegate

```java
  new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemOut())
                .with(RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
                .type(ElementMatchers.is(Foo.class))
                .transform(
                        ( builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module ) -> 
                              builder.method(ElementMatchers.any()).intercept( //how to write ?)

).installOnByteBuddyAgent();
```

Thks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just put the pieces together:

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
  .with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemOut())
  .with(RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
  .type(ElementMatchers.is(Foo.class))
  .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) -> 
    new ByteBuddy().redefine(Bar.class).name(Foo.class.getName()))
  .installOnByteBuddyAgent();
```

This will however only work if the replaced type is shape compatible.